# configuration of xdebug on centos with php-5.2.8

Tags: centos, centos5, php-5.2

I followed the link http://xdebug.org/wizard.php to install xdebug2.2.1 for netbeans7.2 php in my centos5.8 but I dnt have phpize for which i need to install php5-dev and I need to work on  php version 5.2.8 so was unable to install php5-dev in centos5.8

my rpm -qa |grep php gives out following:

php-common-5.2.8-1.fc5.remi  , php-mysql-5.2.8-1.fc5.remi  ,

php-gd-5.2.8-1.fc5.remi  ,  php-5.2.8-1.fc5.remi  ,

php-cli-5.2.8-1.fc5.remi  ,  php-pdo-5.2.8-1.fc5.remi

php-xml-5.2.8-1.fc5.remi

Please help me find a way to install xdebug for the following technical stack
php-5.2.8
centos-5.8

can not change php version but flexible to upgrade or downgrade centos

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all

found answer for my question I needed to install php-devel-5.2.8-1.fc5.remi to make phpize work and then followed the link mention earlier http://xdebug.org/wizard.php .Its working fine.